# Adding 1 to field in a database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, field

I want to add 1 to a rating I click. in my webpage I have 5 buttons labeled, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If I press the button "2", I want the ID to be selected and then the rating 2 column to be update. For example. If I rate Amy as a 4, I want Amy's ID (1) to be searched for and then I want 400 (Rating 4) to have 1 added to it (400+1=401).

How would I do this? I will provide an example of my table below.

My table is like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID|Name|   Email   |Password| Rating 1 | Rating 2 | Rating 3 | Rating 4 | Rating 5 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Amy |H@gmail.com|jaaaaaaa|      11  |   153    |   343    |    400   | 505      |

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2 |Bob |1@gmail.com|haaukanm|       1  |      3   | 44       |    444   | 54       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3 |Bill|aa@mail.com|fsoji443|     431  |    53    | 33       |    41    | 545      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in plain text!! Use proper, modern means of hashing

Comment: Did you try writing a `Update` statement

Comment: UPDATE table SET `Rating 1` = (`Rating 1` + 1), UPDATE table SET `Rating 2` = (`Rating 2` + 1) and so on.

Comment: Also, column-names with spaces is going to cause headaches, because you need to use backticks to identify them, Like `\`Rating 1\``.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the use of **UPDATE** query just like this

```
UPDATE table SET 'Rating 1' = ('Rating 1' + 1) where ID = 1;
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: Not using backticks on `Rating 1` will cause errors.